# How do I get azure DevOps to put the cloudflare url in a PR comment

Tags: azure-devops, cloudflare-pages

My company has an Azure DevOps pipeline which publishes the development branch to cloudflare and prints a link to that deployment in the log.

I would like that link to appear in a PR comment so that the dev doesn't need to click through to the logs to find it.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use this REST API [Pull Request Thread Comments - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-request-thread-comments/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1&tabs=HTTP) in the pipeline.

Result:

[image]

First of all, make sure your build service has permissions to contribute to pull requests in your repository.  Otherwise, you may get the error like this

```
"message":"TF401027: You need the Git 'PullRequestContribute' permission to perform this action. Details: identity 'Build\\xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx', scope 'repository'.
```

There are two build service accounts `ProjectName Build Service (OrganizationName)`  and `Project Collection Build Service (OrganizationName)`. It depends on your pipeline configuration. The doc is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/access-tokens?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).
If you are not sure which account you are using, you can search the id `xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx` in the error message and you will see the account.

[image]

If you are using the yaml pipeline, here is the sample. The first task is to set your link as variable `DeployURL`. Then we can use the variable in the following tasks.

```
trigger: none
jobs:
- job: Job_1
  displayName: Agent job 1
  pool:
    vmImage: windows-2019
  steps:
  - checkout: self

  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: set variable DeployURL
    inputs:
      targetType: inline
      script: >-
        $url="https://dev.azure.com/"
        
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=DeployURL]$url"
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: check the variable DeployURL
    inputs:
      targetType: inline
      script: Write-Host $(DeployURL)
  - task: PowerShell@2
    condition: eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')
    displayName: write comment to the PR with DeployURL
    env:
        MY_ACCESS_TOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
    inputs:
      targetType: inline
      script: >-
        $url = "$($env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI)$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID/_apis/git/repositories/$($env:BUILD_REPOSITORY_NAME)/pullRequests/$($env:SYSTEM_PULLREQUEST_PULLREQUESTID)/threads?api-version=5.1"

        Write-Host "URL: $url"

        $body = @"
              {
                  "comments": [
                    {
                      "parentCommentId": 0,
                      "content": "The DeployURL is  $(DeployURL)",
                      "commentType": 1
                    }
                  ],
                  "status": 4
                }
        "@

        $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method POST -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"} -Body $Body -ContentType application/json
```

If you are using the classic build pipeline, please check the Allow scripts to access the OAuth token.

[image]

The Custom condition is set to only run the task when the build reason is pullrequest.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tested this and it just worked. I didn't need to do anything with the permissions (I mention this in case anyone is brought here looking for help on fixing their permissions).